# Detail button on second view

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, button, controller, navigation

I am new to iOs programming and am having a hard time with the Navigation Controller.
I have a table view which shows a detail-view when an item is selected.
The 'back' button appears correctly at the top of the detail-view, so that is all fine.

Now I want to add a button to the detail view to link to a website. So I tried to add a button to the navigation controller. First I did it in IB, but if you do that it only appears in the first view and disappears in the detail view (and I only want to have it in the detail-view).

Then I tried it with code (added it in the detailviewcontroller in viedDidLoad:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(viewlink:)];
```

The button appears, and I added a function:

```
-(void)viewLink:(id)sender {
 NSLog(@"Went to view 2");
}
```

But when running the app I get the much quoted "-[ItemDetailViewController viewlink:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a13cb0".

What would be the best way to do this?
I have spend hours on this issue by now and am really pulling my hair out as it seems to be such a simple thing, so I must do something basic wrong.

Comment: Just double checking - you have `-(void)viewLink:(id)sender;` in your .h file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the error message, it says "viewlink:" (lowercase l) but your method is named viewLink: (uppercase L).

When calling that method, make sure you use the exact same spelling with the same case since the language is case-sensitive.

You should also have gotten a warning from the compiler (not a run-time error) saying "'ItemDetailViewController' may not respond to -viewlink:".  Watch for and resolve all warnings.

The syntax highlighter will also give an indication that something's wrong.  An unrecognized method will appear black but a recognized one will appear in light blue.

Comment: I was afraid it was a small stupid mistake... In shame I said that adding the function to the .h file and changing the capital fixed the problem. Thanks so much for he help!